# Laravel 5.6 groupBy on collection doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, grouping

GroupBy just doesn't work on collection in Laravel 5.6, it is very annoying when simple things which supposed to work not wirking...

```
$users = Game::orderBy('game_count', 'desc')->get();

$users_grouped = $users->groupBy('user_id');
```

As you might guess `$users_grouped` contains the same collection as `$users` with the same repeating `user_id` values.

I don't get why it doesn't work as expected and how to fix it?

At least `GROUP BY` works with raw DB select hopefully.. But I want to use Eloquent..

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing eloquent's query builder with collections.  They are not the same thing.

groupBy on a query builder instance will use an SQL GROUP BY and give one aggregated result for the column(s) you are grouping on.

groupBy on a collection instance will return a new collection that groups all collected items by the given key's value.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby

If you want to use the query builder's groupBy method, chain it before the `get()`:

```php
$users = Game::orderBy('game_count', 'desc')->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

`get()` executes the query and returns the collection of records.

Comment: I'am confusend not less than Eloquent :) In your example you will get the same result as this `$users = Game::groupBy('user_id')->get();`, so `orderBy` doesn't make a sense in this case.

Comment: @mr.boris your question isn't clear.  So you may want to write a new one and be more clear about what you need.  groupBy how you're using it isn't using Eloquent at all, it's calling groupBy on the collection and it will not be the same collection, it will be grouped entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group the query by user_id just do the groupBy before the get(), as the following row:

```
$users = Game::orderBy('game_count', 'desc')->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

Comment: No, I want to sort query at first and then group it. Sorry, but the query that you've provided doesn't make sense, you can remove `orderBy` operator and you will get the same result..

Answer (score 0):

The rows will be the same. You should make two querys:

```
$users = Game::orderBy('game_count', 'desc')->get();
$users_grouped = Game::orderBy('game_count', 'desc')->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `$users` and `$users_grouped` will be exactly the same in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution for this is the raw SQL query:

```
$users_grouped  = DB::select('SELECT COUNT(id) AS theCount, `user_id` from `quiz_games` GROUP BY `user_id` ORDER BY theCount DESC');
```